# Branch is merging into self on git push

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-push, git-pull

I have a repo set up on GitHub, with a Dev branch, which I clone to my local machine using:

```
git clone https://github....
```

I then switch to my Dev branch using:

```
git checkout -b Dev
```

I then pull just to make sure all is up to date

```
git pull origin Dev
```

I am now in my Dev branch, write some code and add the files using:

```
git add filename
```

I then commit using:

```
git commit -m "message"
```

I then push using:

```
git push origin Dev
```

This works all good. A second user then comes along and enters some code. At the same time I am working on a separate file but we are working on the same branch. I add and commit as before. However, when I try to push, I receive the following:

> To `https://github.com/ex/ex.git`  ! [rejected]
>   Dev -> Dev (fetch first) error: failed to push some
>   refs to '`https://github.com/ex/ex.git`' hint: Updates
>   were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not
>   have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes
>   (e.g., hint: 'git pull') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note
>   about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I do as it says and perform:

```
git pull origin Dev
```

I can then push as before and all seems well. However, back on GitHub when I check the commit history I see this:

```
 Merge branch 'Dev' of https://github.com/ex/ex into Dev
```

amongst the commits I just added. Why is this merge happening? How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: `git pull` is basically `git fetch; git merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge was needed because you and your second user diverged; each of you committed something off of a common base.  Getting back in sync requires combining the two development paths.

A 'merge commit' does no harm whatsoever; it really isn't worth worrying about it.  However, if you want to avoid it, often to keep a cleaner history, you perform:

```
git pull --rebase ...
```

which will rebase your new commits onto whatever is pulled from the repository.  The history will then appear linear.

Here is an example.  A repository with two branches:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all    
* 678ea83 c
| * 2c1e48f b
|/  
* 5836f6f a
```

The result of merge:

```
$ git merge dev
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 b
$ git log --oneline --graph --all
*   6d50134 Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * 2c1e48f b
* | 678ea83 c
|/  
* 5836f6f a
```

Alternately, the result of rebase:

```
$ git rebase dev
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: c
$ git log --oneline --graph --all
* 89a3771 c
* 2c1e48f b
* 5836f6f a
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your last commit was integrated:

- you had to pull because dev@origin was "newer"
- with the pull you merged dev@origin to your local dev
- your local dev had a commit, which you originally wanted to push to origin
- finally dev@origin was merged with your commit (so dev was merged with dev)

Comment: In addition to that, you probably want to ``git pull --rebase`` or set the corresponding flag in your config file.

Comment: You can prevent this on all of your projects by executing these commands now:  `git config --global pull.rebase true` for git >=1.7.9  or `git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always`  for git <1.7.9